# FFMPEG GPU Image Processing

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, gpu, nvidia

I want to resize an image. I used ffmpeg for that. I used the following command

ffmpeg -i in.jpg -vf scale=200:200 -sws_flags lanczos out.png

Whether this command runs in CPU or GPU?? If the command is not running in GPU, how can i set it to run in GPU (NVIDIA) ??

Comment: Have you tried with Opencv? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Answer (score 0):

It runs on the CPU. I don't think the PNG encoder can use the GPU, and neither does the JPEG decoder. You can try the below command and see if there's a speed or GPU utilization difference.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i in.jpg -vf scale=200:200 -sws_flags lanczos out.png
```

Comment: No improvement in speed

Comment: As I suspected. Those input and output codecs don't support a GPU pipeline.

Comment: For those choice of codecs in ffmpeg, you can't. See [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) for possibilities.

Comment: so this kind of image processing could not be done in ffmpeg GPU. rght??

Comment: That's right. Look into imagemagick. It can use OpenCL for processing, but I don't know the details.